# Laravel Livewire 3 unmount hook/lifecycle

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-echo, laravel-reverb

I am wondering if there is any mechanism or hook which would fire when a component unmounts. I looked through both v2 and v3 docs and I couldn't find something like that.

[Use case](https://laracasts.com/series/lukes-larabits/episodes/17): I am looking to integrate Laravel Reverb into my app and I would like a hook to close the ws connection for a certain component with `Echo.leave('channel-name')`.

Comment: When you say *unmounts* do you mean if its removed from the page?

Comment: @Qirel similar to [onUnmounted](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle#onunmounted) from Vue, or the cleanup function returned from React's [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#reference). Basically, the right place to do clean-up work.

Answer (score 0):

For livewire 3

doing a quick search through the livewire code there is the following function within the ComponentHook.php file

```
function callDestroy(...$params) {
    if (method_exists($this, 'destroy')) $this->destroy(...$params);
}
```

this seems to imply if you add a destroy() function to your component class this would handle the "unmount"

it may be the case that you will need to implement some additional Alpine code to really get to the solution that you want.

again in the livewire codebase there is the following documentation:

> In certain scenarios, you might need to unregister global Livewire
> events. For instance, when working with Alpine components and
> `wire:navigate`, multiple listeners may be registered as `init` is
> called when navigating between pages. To address this, utilize the
> `destroy` function, automatically invoked by Alpine. Loop through all
> your listeners within this function to unregister them and prevent any
> unwanted accumulation.

```js
Alpine.data('MyComponent', () => ({
    listeners: [],
    init() {
        this.listeners.push(  
            Livewire.on('post-created', (options) => {  
                // Do something...
            })
        );
    },
    destroy() {
        this.listeners.forEach((listener) => {  
            listener();  
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you link the docs where you found this?

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't in the official documentation that is available online.
The above was found by searching the livewire codebase on github

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Alivewire%2Flivewire%20destroy&type=code

the above link will show you the results that I found for the 'destroy' keyword

---

Then regarding the Alpine if you have a look in the following file: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/e62eb896f6b03f78c8aade9f85ec61dbe075a7f4/docs/javascript.md?plain=1#L10

and search for the quoted information I put